# Emma code coverage tool error - Main method not found

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, emma

I am using Emma code coverage tool and I have Java8. I am new to Emma and there is very less help available. I tried to use following links.

1. http://emma.sourceforge.net/intro.html
2. http://users.csc.calpoly.edu/~jdalbey/309/Lectures/emmademo.html

But I keep getting following error when I try to run:

```
java -cp emma.jar emmarun -jar .../jdk1.4.2/demo/jfc/SwingSet2/SwingSet2.jar 
java -cp TestTools\emma.jar;. emmarun -cp . CircleConverter
```

I also tried options from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19437050/using-emmarun-main-method-not-found) but it didn't help.

Error is-

```
CoverageDemo>java -XX:-UseSplitVerifier -cp TestTools\emma.jar;. emmarun -cp . CircleConverter
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option UseSplitVerifier; support was removed in 8.0
EMMA: no coverage data collected at runtime [all reports will be empty]
EMMA: writing [txt] report to [C:\Users\pkothavale\Downloads\CoverageDemo\coverage.txt] ...
[EMMA v2.0, build 4217]
emmarun: [MAIN_METHOD_NOT_FOUND] application class [CircleConverter] does not have a runnable public main() method
Exception in thread "main" com.vladium.emma.EMMARuntimeException: [MAIN_METHOD_NOT_FOUND] application class [CircleConverter] does not have a runnable public main() method
        at com.vladium.emma.rt.AppRunner._run(AppRunner.java:497)
        at com.vladium.emma.rt.AppRunner.run(AppRunner.java:97)
        at com.vladium.emma.runCommand.run(runCommand.java:247)
        at emmarun.main(emmarun.java:27)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 11
Exception Details:
```

Answer (score 2):

in fact, the problem is due to this line :

```
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 11
```

I found the solution with this link : [java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target JDK 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15122890/java-lang-verifyerror-expecting-a-stackmap-frame-at-branch-target-jdk-1-7)

But in short, java7 introduced stricter verification and to disable it, we can add the option "-XX:-UseSplitVerifier" if you are using java7 or "-noverify" if you are in java8.

So the correct command line for java8 would be :

```
java -noverify -cp emma.jar emmarun -jar .../jdk1.4.2/demo/jfc/SwingSet2/SwingSet2.jar
```