# Java 8: emmarun giving error 'MAIN_CLASS_NOT_FOUND'

Tags: java, emma, emmarun

I am trying to follow the guide from Emma docs: http://emma.sourceforge.net/userguide_single/userguide.html, but the command `java emmarun -cp out Main` gives me an error as below:

```
 emmarun: [MAIN_METHOD_NOT_FOUND] application class [Main] does not have a runnable public main() method
```

I have tried the solutions from the possible duplicate links, but it didn't help.

I am using **Java 8 (jdk/jre 1.8.0_144)**.

Kindly tell me what am I missing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `-XX:-UseSplitVerifier`?

```
java -XX:-UseSplitVerifier emmarun -cp out Main
```

Per [Using emmarun (main method not found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19437050/using-emmarun-main-method-not-found), it looks like Emma has not been updated to keep pace with some JDK changes, but this workaround should do the trick.

Comment: Yes, I have seen that link and tried using that command, but it didn't work. In fact, along with the 'MAIN_CLASS_NOT_FOUND' error, it showed 'Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option UseSplitVerifier; support was removed in 8.0'